# SQL Server : option to specify if Update Transaction was from trigger?

Tags: sql-server, database-trigger

First ever post, please be gentle...

I have a need to update one column when a table is either updated or row(s) inserted, thus I've created a trigger (`AFTER INSERT, UPDATE`). The problem is that it's recursive due to the fact that the insert includes an update statement, thus firing the trigger again.

I've also tried separating the `INSERT` and `UPDATE` into two different triggers, but I've ran into problem with `sp_settriggerorder()` and `trigger_nestlevel()`, because there are other trigger in place, due to out of box application defaults.

My question is, is there any way to use an IF clause stating whether the update came from the application itself or my trigger? Case, if it's my trigger, than I could easily ELSE IF it to a return and it would no longer be recursive.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[JobCardMetlInsertUpdateItemDesc]
ON [dbo].[JobCardMetl] AFTER INSERT
AS 
    BEGIN TRANSACTION [Description]

    UPDATE JobCardMetl
    SET JobCardMetl.Description = item.Description
    FROM JobCardMetl
    INNER JOIN item ON JobCardMetl.Item = item.item
    WHERE JobCardMetl.RecordDate = (SELECT MAX(JobCardMetl.RecordDate) 
                                    FROM JobCardMetl)

    COMMIT TRANSACTION [Description]
```

Comment: Trigger recursion (a trigger directly triggering itself) can be disabled at the database or server(?) level.  Of course that affects everything.

Answer (score 3):

Your trigger is very suspicious: It does not reference the `INSERTED` pseudotable. This means that your trigger is updating records unaffected by the INSERT, always a huge code-smell.

The usual solution to the problem of recursive triggers is to be careful about what columns are being updated, ie. use [`UPDATED()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/update-trigger-functions-transact-sql), and what rows, and the natural business logic should stop the recursion (ie. the nested trigger should find nothing to update, because the guard checks don't qualify).

Ultimately you can use the logical sledgehammer: [`SET CONTEXT_INFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-context-info-transact-sql) and [`CONTEXT_INFO()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/context-info-transact-sql). You check it, set it and clean it in your trigger. If is already set, you know you're nested from the trigger. The cleaning up part is critical. You also pray no other app/dev does the same, as there is only one context info per session (SQL 2016 improves this).

Answer (score 0):

You could check whether the description is still different from what you want it to be updated to. If the same, you do not update. That way you avoid the endless recursion.

Also, with the `WHERE` condition you seem to want to limit the update to the currently inserted record, but for that you can use the virtual `INSERTED` table, which has the records that have been inserted.

Finally, it seems overkill to start a new transaction for an atomic statement. Note that the trigger will anyway execute within the transaction in which the triggering `INSERT` statement executes.

So taking all that together, you could make your trigger as follows (I assume `RecordDate` uniquely identifies a record -- change it to whatever is the primary key):

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[JobCardMetlInsertUpdateItemDesc]
ON [dbo].[JobCardMetl] AFTER INSERT
AS 
    UPDATE JobCardMetl
    SET j.Description = item.Description
    FROM JobCardMetl j
    INNER JOIN item ON j.Item = item.item
    INNER JOIN INSERTED i ON i.RecordDate = j.RecordDate
    WHERE j.Description IS NULL OR j.Description <> item.Description
```